# Difference between transformation and projection?

Tags: transformations, projections

We know that world coordinates $(x_w, y_w)$ transform to viewport coordinates $(x_v, y_v)$ which are the physical device coordinates. And during projection, any point $(x, y, z)$ projects to $(x, y)$ onto the projection plane. My question is: Are projection and transformation both the same?
Please explain it with a small example. I want to understand intuition rather than details proof.

Comment: This question is an exact copy from another network site. See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288153/difference-between-transformation-and-projection). Closing here to avoid further scattering of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A projection is a *kind* of transformation.

A transformation is any modification of a coordinate that expresses that coordinate relative to a coordinate system that is different from its original coordinate system. As such, a transformation involves two coordinate systems: the source and the destination.

A projection is any transformation where the destination coordinate system has fewer dimensions than the source coordinate system. That is, it removes one or more dimensions from the coordinate.

Comment: in transformation both have same dimension?

Comment: @User4567 A transformation could result in any dimension: more, less, the same. Transformation and projection behave like the words "plant" and "tree". Trees are a subcategory of plants. Projections are a subcategory of transformations.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Can you give some references ?