# Difference between 2D and 3D pipeline

Tags: 3d, transformations, projections

**2D transformation and viewing:**
The camera projects the 2D world co-ordinate $(x_w, y_w)$ on its projection plane which co-ordinates $(x_v, y_v)$.

**3D transformation and viewing:**
The camera projects the 3D world co-ordinate $(x_w, y_w, z_w)$ on its projection plane which co-ordinates $(x_v, y_v, z_v)$.Then $(x_v, y_v, z_v)$ can be transforms to $(x_v, y_v)$ of display device coordinates.

My questions are:

$A.$ In **2D transformation and viewing** projection plane is 2D means it has 2 dimensions height and width. But I am confused projection plane which is a plane (2D) has equation is of the form $ax+by+cz+d=0.$ But here $z$ coordinate is missing, so how will it be plane?

In contrast 3D has projection plane  means it has 3 dimensions height, width and depth. But we know that 2D plane $ax+by+cz+d=0.$ But how we're saying 3D?
I am struggling to differentiate projection plane and dimensions. What I have misunderstood in the concepts of both cases?

$B.$ In **2D transformation and viewing** how world co-ordinate $(x_w, y_w)$  is 2D? Because we know real world is 3D.

$C. $ In perspective projection how we will represents vanishing point coordinates in projection plane? For example I catch one image of railway tracks where two parallel lines intersects. During projection what could be it's world co-ordinate and projection plane coordinates respectively? It's normal form of projection from $(x_w, y_w, z_w)$ to $(x_p, y_p,z_{vp})$ in projection plane?

Comment: 2d to 2d is not a projection. Theres no reason to do anything. A) Only one plane is possible in 2d. Its the entire 2d world.  B. is not defined. Its teh application that defines how to do this, in many cases its just a plane but it can also be a origami etc etc.

Comment: "*In perspective projection how we will represents vanishing point coordinates in projection plane?*" Why do you need to?

Comment: @nicol I just want to know the  coordinates of vanishing point..

Comment: @User4567: The vanishing point in what space? And again, why? I've been doing 3D graphics for a while now, and I've never needed to know where the "vanishing point" is.

Comment: @nicol suppose I want to click on one image where 2 parallel lines are intersect like railway tracks. My question is this intersection point is project to projection plane, what it it's coordinates? It transform $(x, y, z) to (x_p, y_p, z_p)$ like normal point projection?

Comment: @User4567 it does not exist in 3D. In 3D they never intersect. So this point does not exist. Since it does not exist, it is not going to do anything in projection transform. so the transform is *nothing* to *undefined*

Comment: @jooja if it doesn't exist in 3D , so why vanishing point exist in 3D where 2 parallel line intersect?

Comment: @User4567 because the objects at infinity get scaled to infinitely small space. But in reality as a mathematical point it does not exsist even in 2D. Since we have nothing that extends to infinity. Its just that the continuation of said lines conceptually intersect. It is not a literal concept but a imaginary one. Its more like if Y then we would have X. But since Y does not actually exsist X does not either, but since Y nearly exsists its still in some cases useful to pretend that X exists. If you want to find said point you need to either do it in 2D or pretend  that it exists

Comment: There is perspective projection also in 2D, it maps to a 1D film. Thus if you want to do perspective projection in 2D, you will get a one-dimensional result.

Comment: If there is a need for further discussions, please continue [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130956/discussion-on-question-by-user4567-difference-between-2d-and-3d-pipeline).

Comment: @joojaa you mean vanishing point doesn't exists. Actually when two parallel lines intersects in infinity they are not actually intersects. During projection normal point projection is possible but vanishing point projection not possible because it is theoretical concepts but practically it isn't exists. And during projection thoses points are actually normal point... Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great deal of literalism in your understanding of concepts.

A "world coordinate" is a term for a coordinate that is in the space you have designated to represent "the world". Whatever that means to your application. Different objects may have different native coordinate systems, but they will be transformed into a common coordinate system, of which you will render some subsection of. We call that coordinate system "world coordinates".

That's it. That's what it means. It doesn't really have anything to do with "the world" in any literal sense.

It can be whatever numerical coordinate system works best for your needs. It can have however many dimensions you feel comfortable giving it.

Similarly, look at your 2D/3D confusion. What is "2D"? If all of your 3D coordinates and transformations and the like all have a Z of zero, is that not exactly equivalent to "2D"?

Any X-dimension is a special-case of the X+1-dimension where the +1 coordinate is 0 and is unchanged by any transformations. So if it makes you feel more comfortable to think of 2D as 3D with a zero Z, where you're projecting these "3D" coordinates onto a plane at zero Z perpendicular to the Z axis, then you can do that and the math still works out.

But really, you should just think of it as 2D. If the source and destination dimensions of your transformation are the same, then it's not a projection. It's just a generic transformation.

Comment: What about ax+by+cz+d=0 in2D and 3D?

Comment: @User4567: What about it? What happens to that equation when Z is zero?

Comment: "If the source and destination dimensions of your transformation are the same, then it's not a projection."---why it's not projection? During projection dimensions also remains same?

Comment: please say when take photo by camera in 2D , it is transformation? But doing same thing in 3D is called projection?? What's the intuition? Please explain?

Comment: @User4567: "*why it's not projection?*" Because that's the *definition* of "projection". [As previously discussed.](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/12282/2654) If the transformation doesn't decrease the dimensionality, then it's not a projection.

Comment: what about my last two question? Please give the answer in briefly.

Comment: @user4567 how the technical trick of doing something actually works, versus how the definition of something works or how you think something works are 3 different things.

Comment: As said in the questions comments, please continue extensive discussions [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130956/discussion-on-question-by-user4567-difference-between-2d-and-3d-pipeline) - @User4567 If you want to address a specific user, use the `@` character and add the **full** user name. You will usually get a suggestion from your browser. The addressed user will be notified.

Comment: @Nicol "zero Z perpendicular to the Z axis "--- you mean projection $xy$ plane  perpendicular to z-axis?